# Clarifying Data Constructor in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In the following:

```
data DataType a = Data a | Datum
```

I understand that Data Constructor are value level function. What we do above is defining their type. They can be function of multiple arity or const. That's fine. I'm ok with saying `Datum` construct `Datum`. What is not that explicit and clear to me here is somehow the difference between the constructor function and what it produce. Please let me know if i am getting it well:

1 - a) Basically writing `Data a`, is defining both a Data Structure and its Constructor function (*as in scala or java usually the class and the constructor have the same name*) ?

2 - b) So if i unpack and make an analogy. With `Data a` We are both defining a Structure(*don't want to use class cause class imply a type already i think, but maybe we could*) of object (Data Structure), the constructor function (Data Constructor/Value constructor), and the later return an object of that object Structure. Finally The type of that Structure of object is given by the Type constructor. An Object Structure in a sense is just a Tag surrounding a bunch value of some type. Is my understanding correct ?

3 - c) Can I formally Say:

- Data Constructor that are Nullary represent constant values -> Return the the constant value itself of which the type is given by the Type Constructor at the definition site.
- Data Constructor that takes an argument represent class of values, where class is a Tag ? -> Return an infinite number of object of that class, of which the type is given by the Type constructor at the definition site.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think you're to much on the imperative side. You're not creating instances. Everything in Haskell is constant. You're not "creating" things; you're _defining_ them. If you type "Datum", that's not returning "Datum"; that's the wrong way to think about it. It's just a value, similar to e.g. the number "3" in C. Similarly, you're not "constructing" a Data object if you're giving it an (potentially complex) argument; you're _defining_ the Data object together with its argument (which might be a complex definition, but nevertheless a definition).

Comment: Data objects without an argument could be considered to be not fully elaborated Data definitions.

Comment: Or rather, `Data` applied to a value of type `Foo` *is* a value of type `DataType Foo`. It doesn't return it so much as it *is* it.

Comment: `Data 'c'`, for example, is just a value of type `DataType Char`. It is entirely distinct from `'c' :: Char`, and `Data` is as much a part of the value as is `c`. In that sense, `Data` is much more than "just" a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of writing this:

```
data DataType a = Data a | Datum
```

Is with generalised algebraic data type (GADT) syntax, using the `GADTSyntax` extension, which lets us specify the types of the constructors explicitly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}

data DataType a where
  Data  :: a -> DataType a
  Datum ::      DataType a
```

(The `GADTs` extension would work too; it would also allow us to specify constructors with different type arguments in the result, like `DataType Int` vs. `DataType Bool`, but that’s a more advanced topic, and we don’t need that functionality here.)

These are exactly the types you would see in GHCi if you asked for the types of the constructor functions with `:type` / `:t`:

```
> :{
| data DataType a where
|   Data  :: a -> DataType a
|   Datum ::      DataType a
| :}

> :type Data
Data :: a -> DataType a

> :t Datum
Datum :: DataType a
```

With `ExplicitForAll` we can also specify the scope of the type variables explicitly, and make it clearer that the `a` in the `data` definition is a separate variable from the `a` in the constructor definitions by also giving them different names:

```
data DataType a where
  Data  :: forall b. b -> DataType b
  Datum :: forall c.      DataType c
```

Some more examples of this notation with standard prelude types:

```
data Either a b where
  Left  :: forall a b. a -> Either a b
  Right :: forall a b. b -> Either a b

data Maybe a where
  Nothing :: Maybe a
  Just    :: a -> Maybe a

data Bool where
  False :: Bool
  True  :: Bool

data Ordering where
  LT, EQ, GT :: Ordering  -- Shorthand for repeated ‘:: Ordering’
```

> I understand that Data Constructor are value level function. What we do above is defining their type. They can be function of multiple arity or const. That's fine. I'm ok with saying Datum construct Datum. What is not that explicit and clear to me here is somehow the difference between the constructor function and what it produce.

`Datum` and `Data` are both “constructors” of `DataType a` values; neither `Datum` nor `Data` is a type! These are just “tags” that select between the possible varieties of a `DataType a` value.

What is produced is always a value of type `DataType a` for a given `a`; the constructor selects which “shape” it takes.

A rough analogue of this is a `union` in languages like C or C++, plus an enumeration for the “tag”. In pseudocode:

```
enum Tag {
  DataTag,
  DatumTag,
}

// A single anonymous field.
struct DataFields<A> {
  A field1;  
}

// No fields.
struct DatumFields<A> {};

// A union of the possible field types.
union Fields<A> {
  DataFields<A>  data;
  DatumFields<A> datum;
}

// A pair of a tag with the fields for that tag.
struct DataType<A> {
  Tag       tag;
  Fields<A> fields;
}
```

The constructors are then just functions returning a value with the appropriate tag and fields. Pseudocode:

```
<A> DataType<A> newData(A x) {
  DataType<A> result;
  result.tag = DataTag;
  result.fields.data.field1 = x;
  return result;
}

<A> DataType<A> newDatum() {
  DataType<A> result;
  result.tag = DatumTag;
  // No fields.
  return result;
}
```

Unions are unsafe, since the tag and fields can get out of sync, but sum types are safe because they couple these together.

A pattern-match like this in Haskell:

```
case someDT of
  Datum  -> f
  Data x -> g x
```

Is a combination of *testing* the tag and *extracting* the fields. Again, in pseudocode:

```
if (someDT.tag == DatumTag) {
  f();
} else if (someDT.tag == DataTag) {
  var x = someDT.fields.data.field1;
  g(x);
}
```

Again this is coupled in Haskell to ensure that you can only ever access the fields if you have checked the tag by pattern-matching.

So, in answer to your questions:

> 1 - a) Basically writing Data a, is defining both a Data Structure and its Constructor function (as in scala or java usually the class and the constructor have the same name) ?

`Data a` in your original code is *not* defining a data structure, in that `Data` is not a separate type from `DataType a`, it’s just one of the possible *tags* that a `DataType a` value may have. Internally, a value of type `DataType Int` is one of the following:

- The tag for `Data` (in GHC, a pointer to an “info table” for the constructor), and a reference to a value of type `Int`.

  ```
  x = Data (1 :: Int) :: DataType Int

         +----------+----------------+     +---------+----------------+
  x ---->| Data tag | pointer to Int |---->| Int tag | unboxed Int# 1 |
         +----------+----------------+     +---------+----------------+
  ```
- The tag for `Datum`, and no other fields.

  ```
  y = Datum :: DataType Int

          +-----------+
  y ----> | Datum tag |
          +-----------+
  ```

In a language with `union`s, the size of a union is the maximum of all its alternatives, since the type must support representing any of the alternatives with mutation. In Haskell, since values are immutable, they don’t require any extra “padding” since they can’t be changed.

It’s a similar situation for standard data types, e.g., a product or sum type:

```
(x :: X, y :: Y) :: (X, Y)
  +---------+--------------+--------------+
  | (,) tag | pointer to X | pointer to Y |
  +---------+--------------+--------------+

Left (m :: M) :: Either M N
  +-----------+--------------+
  | Left tag  | pointer to M |
  +-----------+--------------+

Right (n :: N) :: Either M N
  +-----------+--------------+
  | Right tag | pointer to N |
  +-----------+--------------+
```

> 2 - b) So if i unpack and make an analogy. With Data a We are both defining a Structure(don't want to use class cause class imply a type already i think, but maybe we could) of object (Data Structure), the constructor function (Data Constructor/Value constructor), and the later return an object of that object Structure. Finally The type of that Structure of object is given by the Type constructor. An Object Structure in a sense is just a Tag surrounding a bunch value of some type. Is my understanding correct ?

This is *sort of* correct, but again, the constructors `Data` and `Datum` aren’t “data structures” by themselves. They’re just the names used to *introduce* (construct) and *eliminate* (match) values of type `DataType a`, for some type `a` that is chosen by the caller of the constructors to fill in the `forall`

`data DataType a = Data a | Datum` says:

- *If* some term `e` has type `T`, *then* the term `Data e` has type `DataType T`
- Inversely, *if* some value of type `DataType T` matches the pattern `Data x`, then `x` has type `T` in the scope of the match (`case` branch or function equation)
- The term `Datum` has type `DataType T` for any type `T`

> 3 - c) Can I formally Say:

> Data Constructor that are Nullary represent constant values -> Return the the constant value itself of which the type is given by the Type Constructor at the definition site.

> Data Constructor that takes an argument represent class of values, where class is a Tag ? -> Return an infinite number of object of that class, of which the type is given by the Type constructor at the definition site.

Not exactly. A *type constructor* like `DataType :: Type -> Type`, `Maybe :: Type -> Type`, or `Either :: Type -> Type -> Type`, or `[] :: Type -> Type` (list), or a *polymorphic* data type, represents an “infinite” family of concrete types (`Maybe Int`, `Maybe Char`, `Maybe (String -> String)`, …) but only in the same way that `id :: forall a. a -> a` represents an “infinite” family of functions (`id :: Int -> Int`, `id :: Char -> Char`, `id :: String -> String`, …).

That is, the type `a` here is a *parameter* filled in with an *argument* value given by the caller. Usually this is implicit, through type inference, but you can specify it explicitly with the `TypeApplications` extension:

```
-- Akin to: \ (a :: Type) -> \ (x :: a) -> x
id        :: forall a. a   -> a
id x = x

id @Int   ::           Int -> Int
id @Int 1 ::                  Int

Data           :: forall a. a    -> DataType a
Data @Char     ::           Char -> DataType Char
Data @Char 'x' ::                   DataType Char
```

The *data constructors* of each instantiation don’t really have anything to do with each other. There’s nothing in common between the instantiations `Data :: Int -> DataType Int` and `Data :: Char -> DataType Char`, apart from the fact that they share the same tag name.

Another way of thinking about this in Java terms is with the *visitor pattern*. `DataType` would be represented as a function that accepts a “`DataType` visitor”, and then the constructors don’t correspond to separate data types, they’re just the *methods of the visitor* which accept the fields and return some result. Writing the equivalent code in Java is a worthwhile exercise, but here it is in Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
-- (Allows passing polymorphic functions as arguments.)

type DataType a
  = forall r.    -- A visitor with a generic result type
  r              -- With one “method” for the ‘Datum’ case (no fields)
  -> (a -> r)    -- And one for the ‘Data’ case (one field)
  -> r           -- Returning the result

newData :: a -> DataType a
newData field = \ _visitDatum visitData -> visitData field

newDatum :: DataType a
newDatum = \ visitDatum _visitData -> visitDatum
```

Pattern-matching is simply running the visitor:

```
matchDT :: DataType a -> b -> (a -> b) -> b
matchDT dt visitDatum visitData = dt visitDatum visitData
-- Or: matchDT dt = dt
-- Or: matchDT = id

-- case someDT of { Datum -> f; Data x -> g x }
-- f :: r
-- g :: a -> r
-- someDT :: DataType a
--        :: forall r. r -> (a -> r) -> r

someDT f (\ x -> g x)
```

Similarly, in Haskell, data constructors are just the ways of *introducing and eliminating* values of a user-defined type.

Comment: Thank you so much for this !!! Excellent/brillant answer! on point !

Answer (score 2):

> What is not that explicit and clear to me here is somehow the difference between the constructor function and what it produce

I'm having trouble following your question, but I think you are complicating things. I would suggest not thinking too deeply about the "constructor" terminology.

But hopefully the following helps:

Starting simple:

> data DataType = Data Int | Datum

The above reads "Declare a new *type* named `DataType`, which has the possible *values* `Datum` or `Data <some_number>` (e.g. `Data 42`)"

So e.g. `Datum` is a value of type `DataType`.

Going back to your example with a type parameter, I want to point out what the syntax is doing:

```
     
data DataType a = Data a | Datum 
     ^        ^        ^           These things appear in type signatures (type level)
                  ^        ^       These things appear in code (value level stuff)
```

There's a bit of punning happening here. so in the `data` declaration you might see "`Data Int`" and this is mixing type-level and value-level stuff in a way that you wouldn't see in code. In code you'd see e.g. `Data 42` or `Data someVal`.

I hope that helps a little...

Comment: yes it does thanks. I like the punning comment :) !! Thanks to my years working with semantics technology and OWL 2 Reasoning :)